# How to tell when Facebook's servers are making a request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok, so many of my pages are facebook objects, problem is that some of them take a few seconds to load but facebook seems to have a very small timeout when trying to scrape these pages for metadata.
I would like to know if there is any way to know when Facebook's servers are making the request so that I can render just the metadata and make the page load faster to avoid timeouts.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by my pages are facebook objects?

Comment: So your pages are called by Facebook but also used interactively by users or by other applications?

Comment: Just check for the user agent of the Facebook scraper. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo

Comment: I can't believe I missed that in the documentation, thanks CBroe, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CBroe pointed out in the comments, in the like button documentation (why it's here instead of in the open graph documentation I don't know) it points out to using the user agent to identify facebook requests:
[Like Button - Scraper Info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo)